# Failed to send message using RTCDataChannel on iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

I have managed to share video and audio between A and B,and i find RTCDataChannelState have changed to kRTCDataChannelStateOpen.

```
- (void)channelDidChangeState:(RTCDataChannel*)channel
```

`sendData` also can return YES,however i can't receive the message and

```
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection*)peerConnection
    didOpenDataChannel:(RTCDataChannel*)dataChannel
```

never called.I think it should be called after ice state changed to `RTCICEConnectionConnected` however it doesn't!
Create datachannel:

```
RTCDataChannelInit *DataChannelInit = [[RTCDataChannelInit alloc] init];
    DataChannelInit.maxRetransmits = 0;
    DataChannelInit.isOrdered=false;
    DataChannelInit.maxRetransmitTimeMs = -1;
    DataChannelInit.isNegotiated = false;
    DataChannelInit.streamId = 25;
    RTCDataChannel *dataChannel =[_peerConnection createDataChannelWithLabel:@"commands" config:DataChannelInit];
    dataChannel.delegate=self;
    self.datachannel = dataChannel;
```

My offer and anwser:

```
- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultOfferConstraints {
  NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" value:@"true"],
      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" value:@"true"]
  ];

    NSArray *optionalConstraints = @[
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"internalSctpDataChannels" value:@"true"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement" value:@"true"]
                                      ];
  RTCMediaConstraints *constraints =
      [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
          initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                   optionalConstraints:optionalConstraints];
  return constraints;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach offer/answer SDP and WebRTC framework version that will be more easy identify the issue.

The following delegate should call at receiver side after you set the RemoteDescription, if you add the data channel properly

```
-(void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
   didOpenDataChannel:(RTCDataChannel *)dataChannel {
     NSLog(@"Received remote data channel %ld ", (long)dataChannel.readyState);
     dc = dataChannel;
     dc.delegate = self;
}
```

> You should create the Offer after creating data channel, so that offer will carry the data channel details
>
> No need of creating data channel at receiver side as data channel is full duplex.

Comment: I create the Offer after creating data channel,but `didOpenDataChannel` wasn't called after i set the RemoteDescription.

Comment: Can you provide the offer sdp with pastebin?

Comment: Thank you for your help and here is my [offer sdp](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/iY9h0SVS)